# Laravel 4 query from multiple table;

Tags: laravel

I have three tables

```
     DGRS TABLE                     SPVS TABLE         LOCS TABLE
    ------------------             ------------       ---------------------
    dgr_date                       sid (PK)           mloc (PK)
    mc_loc (fk:locs:mloc)          sname              spid (fk:spvs:sid)
    ws                             state
    daily_gen
```

mysql query is successfully returning the result:

```
select spvs.sname, sum(dgrs.daily_gen) 
from spvs, dgrs, locs
where spvs.sid=locs.spid and locs.mloc=dgrs.mc_loc and dgrs.dgr_date='2008-04-01'
group by dgrs.dgr_date, spvs.sname;
```

Model

```
class Dgr extends \Eloquent {

    public function loc(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Loc');

    }
    public function spv(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Spv');

    }

}

class Loc extends \Eloquent {

    public function dgr(){

        return $this->hasMany('Dgr');
    }

}


class Spv extends \Eloquent {

    public function spv(){

        return $this->hasMany('Loc');
    }

}
```

How to write mysql query into Laravel? Please suggest.

I tried like this:

```
$dgrs=DB::table('dgrs')

                        ->join('locs', 'locs.mloc', '=', 'dgrs.mc_loc')
                        ->join('spvs', 'spvs.sid', '=', 'locs.spid')
                        ->select('spvs.sname')
                        ->sum('dgrs.daily_gen')
                        ->where('dgr_date', '=','2008-04-01')
                        ->groupBy('dgr_date', 'spvs.sname')
                        ->get();
```

Getting the error:

Call to a member function where() on a non-object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the joins and rest of your query works, you only need to move the `sum()` part into the `select()` and use `DB::raw()` so it gets interpreted as SQL function.

```
$dgrs=DB::table('dgrs')
        ->join('locs', 'locs.mloc', '=', 'dgrs.mc_loc')
        ->join('spvs', 'spvs.sid', '=', 'locs.spid')
        ->select('spvs.sname', DB::raw('SUM(dgrs.daily_gen)'))
        ->where('dgr_date', '=','2008-04-01')
        ->groupBy('dgr_date', 'spvs.sname')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Mr. lukasgeiter, Perfect answer. Please consider my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

I put mysql query into:

DB::select(DB::raw());

Like

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select spvs.sname, sum(dgrs.daily_gen) from spvs, dgrs, locs
              where spvs.sid=locs.spid and locs.mloc=dgrs.mc_loc and dgrs.dgr_date='2008-04-01'
              group by dgrs.dgr_date, spvs.sname"));
```

And it produce the result as displayed by mysql.